# Maven Kotlin plugin with JDK 17 not working

Tags: kotlin

Upgraded Kotlin from 1.5 to 1.8 today: build fails in JDK 17 due to:

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field protected java.io.OutputStream java.io.FilterOutputStream.out accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @2ba9f986
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
        at com.intellij.util.io.IOUtil.syncStream(IOUtil.java:217)
```

tried to add the following to my Maven configuration:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <jvmTarget>${java.version}</jvmTarget>
        <args>
            <arg>"--add-opens java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED"</arg>
        </args>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

but the problem is still there.

[Official documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/maven.html) does not seem to provide any info on this. Online search did not find much, apart from [something about Gradle](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45545)

Is there any Maven-plugin configuration to fix it? (ie build Kotlin 1.8 on JDK 17) or is that not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For our Kotlin project build with Maven, We have the following file `.mvn/jvm.config` in the project folder. The content should be as follows:

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: yep, it worked! thx. btw, please update, as you have weird · symbol instead of = in your answer